# Click on all the links on a webpage Casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm beginner programmer in javascript and casperjs.

I'm trying to click on all the links found on a page.

```
 casper.then(function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(__utils__.findAll('a'), function(e) {
        this.click('a');
        console.log('clicked ok, new location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
        casper.back();
        console.log('clicked ok, new location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up a lot of things here:

- `__utils__` is the clientutils module and is only available in the page context (inside `casper.evaluate()`). The page context is sandboxed, so you cannot use variables from outside or pass DOM nodes to the outside.
- CasperJS is organized in steps, but not all functions are step functions. `casper.click()` is a blocking click call, but `casper.back()` is asynchronous.
- `casper.click()` clicks on the first element that matches the selector, but since the selector is always the same for every iteration, the same element would be clicked every time. You have to keep track which element you clicked already. This can be done in the page context, but then you can't use `casper.click()` anymore or this can be achieved with XPath expressions.

Example code:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.then(function() {
    var count = this.getElementsInfo("a").length;
    for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++){
        this.thenClick(x('(//a)['+i+']'))
            .then(function(){
                console.log('clicked ok, new location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
            })
            .back()
            .then(function(){
                console.log('back to location ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be useful:

```
casper.then(function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(__utils__.findAll('a'), function(e) {
        e.click();
        console.log('clicked ok, new location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
        casper.back();
        console.log('clicked ok, new location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
    });
```

Comment: tried using this function but it didn't work. There was no output.